# Problems using <ul> and <li> to read the elements of a list with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, html-lists, gettext

I'm new in Selenium and I have a problem when accessing a list in which to show the list you must click and then select a specific option, my option es "NATURAL", my page have the next code:

```
   <div id="tipoIdentificacion_panel" class="ui-selectonemenu-panel ui-widget-content ui- 
    corner-all ui-helper-hidden ui-shadow" style="">
   <div class="ui-selectonemenu-items-wrapper" style="height:auto">
   
   <ul class="ui-selectonemenu-items ui-selectonemenu-list ui-widget-content ui-widget 
   ui-corner-all ui-helper-reset">
   <li class="ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all ui-state- 
    highlight" data-label="Seleccione...">Seleccione...</li>
   <li class="ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all" data- 
    label="NATURAL">NATURAL</li>
   <li class="ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all" data- 
    label="JURIDICA EXTRANJERA">JURIDICA EXTRANJERA</li>
   </ul>
   </div>
   </div>
```

in Java I have the next code for identify the elements of the list

```
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 50);             
                    
    WebElement TipoPersonas= 
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*@id="tipoPersona_panel"]/div/ul"));
    List<WebElement> TipoPersona=TipoPersonas.findElements(By.tagName("li"));       
        
    for (WebElement lis : TipoPersona) {
     if (lis.getText().equals("NATURAL")) {
         lis.click();
       }
```

The problem is that never find the value "NATURAL" because the value the `lis.getText()` always is null and the comparision it's no possible, could we help me?

Comment: What website is it?

Answer (score 0):

What I can see is you are getting null pointer exception because of wrong xpath syntax for variable **`TipoPersonas`**, you are missing a square bracket after **`//*`**. And I don't see any tag having id as **`tipoPersona_panel`**.

So the changed xpath will be: **`//div[@id = 'tipoIdentificacion_panel']//div//ul`**.

After making the changes code looks like this:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 50);             
                
WebElement TipoPersonas= 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='tipoIdentificacion_panel']//div//ul"));
List<WebElement> TipoPersona=TipoPersonas.findElements(By.tagName("li"));       
    
for (WebElement lis : TipoPersona) {
 if (lis.getText().equals("NATURAL")) {
     lis.click();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the code:

```
 List<WebElement> TipoPersonas= 
    driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='ui-selectonemenu-items-wrapper']/ul/li"));  
    System.out.println("Size Tipopersona: " + TipoPersonas.size());   
    for (WebElement lis : TipoPersonas) {
          System.out.println("Value is" + lis.getText());    
          if(lis.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("NATURAL")) {
          lis.click();
     }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but my problem continues, since it does not bring me or compare the values.

Answer (score 0):

To simply click an element with the NATURAL value we do this. You can make it into an array and loop click if you want.

```
WebElement TipoPersonas=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.ui-selectonemenu-items-wrapper>ul>li[data-label='NATURAL']"));
TipoPersonas.click();
```